# WPF datagrid IsReadOnly exception

Tags: c#, wpf, checkbox, datagrid, readonly-attribute

I have a datagrid where i have added a Checkbox column. I want the entire datagrid to be IsReadOnly except the Checkbox column. I have tried:

```
  <DataGrid x:Name="DataGridView_Customer_Information" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,200,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="410" Width="697" CanUserAddRows="False" IsReadOnly="True" >
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridCheckBoxColumn x:Name="CheckBoxSelectRow" IsReadOnly="False"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

But i can imagine that `<DataGridCheckBoxColumn x:Name="CheckBoxSelectRow" IsReadOnly="False"/>` is overruled by the previous statement. Since its only one column that needs to be able to allow edit (allow to checkmark the checkbox) is it possible to make an expection in the IsReadOnly?

Thanks in advanced

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two options.
Both assumes, that `DataGrid.AutoGenerateColumns` is `False`.

1. Remove `IsReadOnly="True"` from `DataGrid` element and set `IsReadOnly` for each column: `False` for `DataGridCheckBoxColumn`, `True` for the rest of columns.
2. Leave `IsReadOnly="True"` for `DataGrid` as is, and instead of `DataGridCheckBoxColumn` add `DataGridTemplateColumn` with `CheckBox` inside template:

   ```
   <DataGrid IsReadOnly="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding Guests}">
       <DataGrid.Columns>
           <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Is invited">
               <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                   <DataTemplate>
                       <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsInvited}"/>
                   </DataTemplate>
               </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
           </DataGridTemplateColumn>

           <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Name}" IsReadOnly="False"/>
       </DataGrid.Columns>
   </DataGrid>
   ```

The second approach has another benefit. Default behavior of `DataGridCheckBoxColumn` is weird - to change check mark you need to select cell first, which is not convenient. `CheckBox` inside `DataGridTemplateColumn` accepts user input *without* selecting cell, and this looks natural.

Comment: Thanks for the answer

Comment: Nice idea using `DataGridTemplateColumn` instead of `DataGridCheckBoxColumn` for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

You can set each other column `IsReadOnly` to `false`.

**Update**

Or you can add into `DataGrid.Resources` styles for other columns

```
<DataGrid.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridTextColumn}">
        <Setter Property="IsReadOnly" Value="True" />
    </Style>
</DataGrid.Resources>
```

Comment: Well the column names are not defined in the WPF, the Datagrid takes the values from the SQL database.

Comment: What if `AutoGenerateColumns` is set to `"True"` ?

Comment: Maybe you can set it's `IsReadOnly` properties to `false` from code behind except `CheckBoxColumn`.